# How to unprotect a worksheet if I made a syntax error while protecting it in the first place using Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

A simple syntax error on my part. In a block of code, I had a line to protect a worksheet.

```vb
Sheets("xyz").Protect password = "abc", AllowFiltering:=True
```

Now I'm unable to unprotect the sheet using the password "abc". I realized I missed a `:` after `password`. Can anyone help figure out the password in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you did is to write a boolean expression as password. VBA will evaluate the term `password = "abc"` to either True or False - likely to False except if you have somewhere a variable `password` declared that contains `abc`.

I couldn't figure out what exactly is written as password. Tried several variations and this is the outcome:

```
' Sheets("xyz").Unprotect "False"    ' Didn't work
' Sheets("xyz").Unprotect "0"        ' Didn't work
' Sheets("xyz").Unprotect 0          ' Didn't work
Sheets("xyz").Unprotect False        ' Works!
```

General advice: Define your password as (named) constant so you don't have to search the code for all protect/unprotect statements if one day you want to change it.

```
Const MySecret = "abc"
...
Sheets("xyz").Protect Password:=MySecret
...
Sheets("xyz").Unprotect Password:=MySecret
```

And I assume that you don't have a variable `Password` declared. In that case, using `Option Explicit` would have prevented that error because the compiler would have complained.

Comment: It worked! However, it is not the same as setting the password to False. Because I tried using the Unprotect Sheet feature in the ribbon toolbar and entered False as the password - this obviously didn't work. Had to be done in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If the following:

```
Sheets("xyz").Protect password = "abc"
```

locks the sheet, for the reasons FunThomas explains - then strictly speaking the following would unlock it:

```
Sheets("xyz").Unprotect password = "abc"
```

Comment: I tried this approach as well and it works just fine!